# When to use 8, 16, or 32 bit displacement when assembling branch machine code?

Tags: assembly, branch, machine-code, 68000

I have a question regarding the machine code of operations like BRA, BCC, etc... in 68K Assembly.

Is there a rule to know if the size of the displacement will be 8, 16, or 32 bits? For example, I wrote a program with -6 byte displacement using the BRA operation and the machine code for it was:

```
60FA  (8 bit displacement)
```

Then I wrote a program that had 6 byte displacement for the BRA operation and the machine code was:

```
6000 0006   (16 bit displacement)
```

Are positive displacements always 16 bit displacements?

Here is what the manual says for the BRA opcode which further confused me:

```
8-Bit Displacement field: Twos complement integer specifying the number of bytes
between the branch instruction and the next instruction to be executed if the
condition is met.

16-Bit Displacement field: Used for the displacement when the 8-bit displacement
field contains $00.

32-Bit Displacement field: Used for the displacement when the 8-bit displacement
field contains $FF.
```

I was told if the displacement was greater than byte size to use 16-bit but is 6 not less than byte size?

Furthermore, are displacements always sign extended like the "A" in the first example?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you used a single pass assembler. So it did not know how far ahead it needed to jump and it defaulted to 16 bit.

Comment: I'm a beginner in assembly so I don't know what a single pass assembler is. I'm using the easy68K simulator if that helps any.

Comment: It just means it goes through your code once. Obviously when it sees a forward jump it does not yet know how far the destination is going to be so it needs to be conservative. You might have an option to tell it to expect shorter distance, or use multiple passes. In any case, 8 bit positive displacement would be legal, just your assembler was not smart enough to generate it.

Comment: So its just my assembler and a 8 bit displacement would be legal. OK, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An assembler will mainly do what you tell it to. My 68k assemblers expose different behavior - some will dumbly just translate what I told them, some will issue warnings and/or errors when the branch offset size is too small or too large to reach a label, and some others will do several passes to optimize branch sizes. It depends on your assembler.

Most assemblers I know will choose word size offsets if you don't explicitly tell them otherwise (using a .S or .L suffix).

But even if your assembler optimizes for you, a good assembler programmer has a sense of approximately what branch size he will need to reach a label.

```
   BRA.S    label
   BRA.W    label
   BRA.L    label ; (68020 and up only)
```

produce three different offset values (byte, word, longword size) to reach their target. Offset values are 2s-complement, so +-126, +-65534 and +-2^-a lot. In case your chosen branch type uses too much of an offset, you are wasting memory space and CPU (instruction fetch takes longer).